# How can I set different sets of fields to create and update a resource in Laravel nova?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I want to show a different set of fields with different settings when creating and editing a resource.

how to implement it with Laravel Nova ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I assume you've seen this: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/fields.html#defining-fields

Comment: @Sjeiti how does it help to display some fields for creation, and other fields for editing?

Comment: I thought you had trouble creating fields. But your comment clarifies you want the creation to differ from the editing. Maybe you should reword that in your question.

Comment: @Sjeiti did you mean these methods?

```hideWhenCreating()
hideWhenUpdating()```

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/fields.html#showing-hiding-fields

Yes, it will do. Thank.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this condition inside the fields function to check if this is an update or create request,
For example

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    if($request->resourceId === null)
    {
        //this is a create request
        return
        [
            ID::make('ID', 'tenant_id')->sortable(),
            Text::make('Userame', 'username'),
            Image::make('Profile', 'user_file')
        ]
    }
    else
    {
        return
        [
            ID::make('ID', 'tenant_id')->sortable(),
            Image::make('Profile', 'user_file')
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Since v3.1.0 you can use the following methods:

- public function fieldsForIndex(Request $request)
- public function fieldsForDetail(Request $request)
- public function fieldsForCreate(Request $request)
- public function fieldsForUpdate(Request $request)